# Which is correct: "of interest" or "in question"?

Tags: phrase-usage, contemporary-english

Let's say that I have a shopping list with a bunch of items.

I want to contact a seller, and purchase the items.

Let's say I have a conversation with the seller about a particular item.  Let's just say the item is a television.

As I communicate the seller for a long period of time, do I refer to the item (i.e. television)

- item of interest
  or
- item in question?

Also, could someone please elaborate on when we should use "of interest" and when should we use "in question"? Are the 2 phrases always interchangeable?
What is the difference between the 2 phrases?

Comment: Be careful of using *of interest*, as there is a somewhat sinister meaning attached to *person of interest* (used by police in describing someone they  want to speak to, and quite possibly charge with a crime). This might carry over to innocuous situations, such as item of interest (at least in the mind of the listener). But *item in question* sounds unduly formal, maybe even pretentious. You could say, *the item you're interested in*, which has none of the drawbacks of the other two.

Comment: Since we've not been given the actual sentence you're trying to write, I have to put this on hold as unclear. There are a few general things we can say, though: 1. Absolutely no two phrases are always interchangeable. 2. The difference between two phrases can be looked up in a dictionary. 3. In your case there is no reason to use either in the first place. In fact I'd strongly advise against it. There is no reason whatsoever to call a TV set an "item of interest" when you can just call it a "TV set", especially when everyone involved knows full well you're talking about a TV set.